# Confluence Word Tagging?

Tags: confluence

Currently setting up a confluence wiki and simple question, is there a way to create a link to specific words?

I would like to have a contents section that would list out all the stored procedures that are mentioned and when clicked will take the user to that specific word or section.

For (bad) example:

Process 1 is using *stored procedure x* to create tables so that *stored procedure y* can pick them up.

List of Stored Procedures:

- stored procedure x
- stored procedure y

I tried to set headings but headings seem to be everything up until a newline (unless I missed something).

Answer (score 0):

Ended up making a custom macro to perform this.

Example:
Process 1 is using ***stored procedure x*** to create *My.Table* to be used with ***stored procedure y***

Returns:

**Stored Procedures**

- stored procedure x
- stored procedure y

**Tables**

- My.Table

How it works:
Based on whether text is Italic and then Bold or just italic, depends on where the values are returned.